# Right cosets of $K=\{1,17\}$ in $U_{32}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

How can we list the distinct right cosets of $K=\{1,17\}$ in $U_{32}$, the set of positive integers relatively prime to $32$?

Comment: Where are you experiencing any difficulties?

Comment: What's your plan of attack?

Comment: I am multiplying each element of K by a in G.

Comment: But the answers do not match

Comment: "the answers"? It'd nice if you'd shown your work. To check your understanding, perhaps give an example of just a single coset of {1,17} and how you got it. (Note that left and right cosets are all the same here since the group is abelian.)

Answer (score 2):

First: list the elements in $U_{32}$, and determine $|U_{32}|$. The number of cosets (right or left) of a subgroup in a group is given by the index of $K \leq U_{32}:\;$ $[U_{32} : K] = \dfrac {|U_{32}|}{|K|}$.

*That will get you started*:

- Know how many elements there are in $U_{32}$, and what they are, and
- then determine the number of cosets.
- Then determine the right cosets, knowing there are necessarily $|K| = 2$ elements in each each coset.
- And recall that the right (or left) cosets of $K$ in $U_{32}\;$ form a
  *partition* of $\;U_{32}$.

Comment: I also like this approach - to give them enough detail and have them crank out the details! +1

Comment: Have you made any progress on this, James?